# Agregar parámetro a una consulta myslq con PHP

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente script:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["proveedor"]!=""){
    include "../../php/conexion.php";
    $params = array_filter($_POST);

    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../marcas.php';</script>";
     }

?>
```

Este script funciona bien. La idea es que inserte los datos en una tabla en la que se están listando una serie de MARCAS.
Previamente, existe un sistema para crear proveedores con sus diferentes datos, para que en este script, pueda recogerlos en un `select` y relacionar la MARCA que se está creando, con su respectivo proveedor.

Lo que necesito hacer es que este script me recoja el `id` del proveedor de la tabla de proveedores y lo inserte en una columna  **id_proveedor** en la tabla de MARCAS, con el respectivo proveedor seleccionado.

Para ello he probado el siguiente `script`:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["proveedor"]!=""){
    include "../../php/conexion.php";

    $params = array_filter($_POST);
    $params['id_proveedor'] = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_POST[proveedor]\"";
    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../marcas.php';</script>";
     }

?>
```

Al hacer el `echo` de la **$sql**, saltan todos los valores, y en el **id_proveedor** salta la sentencia sql tal y como está escrita, salvo por el valor **$_POST** que lo recoge correctamente.

No estoy encontrando la manera de que el script la variable **$params['id_proveedor']** recupere correctamente el dato.

Algo me está faltando hacer previamente, como un `fetch_array` o `query` de esa consulta, pero no estoy sabiendo hacerlo.

**EDIT1:**
He probado este otro `script` también:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["proveedor"]!=""){
    include "../../php/conexion.php";

    $params = array_filter($_POST);
    $id_proveedor = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_POST[proveedor]\"";
    $params['id_proveedor'] = array($id_proveedor);
    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  // para el campo de fecha de creacion

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    // print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../marcas.php';</script>";
     }

?>
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\productos\php\registro_marcas.php
>   on line 21

Además, guarda los datos, pero solo queda el **id_proveedor** en 0.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

He corregido el `script` y me ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
if($_POST["nombre"]!="" && $_POST["proveedor"]!=""){
    include "../../php/conexion.php";
    $params = array_filter($_POST);

    $id_proveedor = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_POST[proveedor]\"";

    $result_id_proveedor = $con->query($id_proveedor);
    $obj = $result_id_proveedor->fetch_object();
    $params['id_proveedor'] = $obj->id;

    $params['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($params));
    $values = '"'.  implode('","',array_values ($params))  . '"';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO marcas ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
    $query = $con->query($sql);
    print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../marcas.php';</script>";
     }

?>
```

Mi problema principal es que me cuesta transformar los datos en el tipo de dato necesario para que las consultas a la base de datos, sean las correctas.

Básicamente encontré una manera de hacerlo y que los datos se inserten correctamente en la base de datos.

Todo salió de otra de mis preguntas realizadas y con un problema similar:
[Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267839/recoverable-fatal-error-object-of-class-mysqli-result-could-not-be-converted-to)