# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer funcionar el siguiente script:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET["id"])) {
    print "<script>alert(\"No se pudo identificar marca. Consulte la base de datos.\");window.location='../editar_marca.php';</script>";
    exit();
} else{
    require_once ("../../php/conexion.php");

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $_GET['descripcion'];
    $proveedor = $_GET['proveedor'];
    $id_proveedor_seleccionado = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = \"$_GET[proveedor]\"";
    $id_proveedor = $con->query($id_proveedor_seleccionado);
    $created_at = date('d-m-Y'); //Hoy en el formato dia-mes-año

    $sql = "UPDATE marcas SET
    nombre = '$nombre',
    descripcion = '$descripcion',
    proveedor = '$proveedor',
    id_proveedor =  '$id_proveedor',
    WHERE id = '$id'";

    $query = $con->query($sql);
    if($query!=null){
        print "<script>alert(\"Edición exitosa.\");window.location='../editar_marca.php';</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

La idea es que actualice la información de una tabla en la que se vuelcan datos de diferentes **MARCAS**.
Previamente, se crea la marca con el nombre, una descripción, y el proveedor previamente cargado con su respectivo **id**.

El problema que tengo es que necesito recuperar el **id** del proveedor de la tabla **PROVEEDORES** y volcarlo en la tabla de **MARCAS**. En este caso, necesito hacer una actualización, debido a que el script se refiere a una edición de los datos cargados previamente.

El resultado que me da es el siguiente:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be
>   converted to string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estudiomanager.com\system\productos\php\guardar_marca_editada.php
>   on line 19

La línea 19 se refiere a **UPDATE**, en la parte del `id_proveedor=$id_proveedor`.

Además, he hecho `echo` de todas las variables y se manifiestan correctamente, sobre todo la variable **$id_proveedor_seleccionado**, pero no puedo dar con la forma correcta de que me tome el dato del **id** del proveedor seleccionado y volcarlo en la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estás intentando convertir un objeto en una cadena de texto (`string`).

Puedes comprobarlo si ejecutas:

```
var_dump($id_proveedor);
```

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
$result_id_proveedor = $con->query($id_proveedor_seleccionado);
$obj = $result_id_proveedor->fetch_object();
$id_proveedor = $obj->id;
```

Ahora en `$id_proveedor` hay un dato tipo `string` y puedes usarlo en la siguiente consulta, tambien puedes aplicar lo siguiente:

```
$pro = $result_id_proveedor->fetch_assoc();
$id_proveedor = $pro['id'];
```

**Nota:** Cuando quieras que una consulta te retorne un solo valor limita la misma con `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Gracias, los problemas que tengo son siempre de convertir el objeto que estoy tomando con php para convertirlo en el string que necesito leer. Tengo un problema similar en la siguiente pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267342/agregar-par%C3%A1metro-a-una-consulta-myslq-con-php

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es en la consulta donde obtienes los probedores  cambia la condicion por nombre = '".$_GET[proveedor]."' para poder obtener el valor de tu GET

ejemplo:

```
$id_proveedor_seleccionado = "SELECT id FROM proveedores WHERE nombre = '".$_GET['proveedor']."'";
```

Comment: Ese parte funciona correctamente, al hacer echo de esa variable, la consulta mysql que resulta está bien. El problema es cuando quiero que esa consulta sea correctamente interpretada por PHP para que el resultado sea el **id** correspondiente al **nombre**.

Comment: puedes revisar que valor te regresa $id_proveedor = $con->query($id_proveedor_seleccionado);

Comment: Aquí no me devuelve nada, solo el error que tengo formulado en la pregunta. Me está faltando convertir las consultas en strings, así me puede devolver el dato que necesito.

Comment: Tengo un problema similar en esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267342/agregar-par%C3%A1metro-a-una-consulta-myslq-con-php